# Is it possible to analyze memory usage from NodeJS program, in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I tried searching both stackoverflow and vs code github repo.

Is it possible to analyze the memory consumption of a node.js program, being debugged in VS code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VS Code does not have a builtin memory profiling story currently (as of 1.16). You should be able to use any standard node.js profiling technique to monitor memory though. For example:

- [process.memoryUsage()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage)
- [memwatch-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch-next)
- [Chrome devtools](https://www.nearform.com/blog/self-detect-memory-leak-node/)